# Where does this proof use the fact that $f'$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reading part of a proof where $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Then the proof starts as follows:

---

Suppose $f'(x_0) > 0$. Since $x_0$ is an interior point of $\mathcal{O}$ and the function $f' : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we can choose $r > 0$ such that the closed interval $[x_0 - r, x_0 + r] \subseteq \mathcal{O}$

---

I don't understand how this follows from continuity. Since $x_0 \in \text{ int } \mathcal{O}$, we can choose an open ball about $x_0$ contained in $\mathcal{O}$. But how can we include the endpoints? I'm guessing that this is where continuity of $f'$ comes into play, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I mean, if it contains an open interval (which it does because it's open) then it contains any closed interval of a smaller size, right? Like, $(a,b)\supseteq [c,d]$ for any $a<c<d<b$.

Comment: Let your open ball about $x_0$ be $(x_0-s,x_0+s)$. Then choose $r=s/2$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: The proof is probably about to claim that $f'([x_0-r,x_0+r]\subset (0,\infty)$, which does use continuity.

Comment: Oh the full sentence was "Since $x_0$ is an interior point of $\mathcal{O}$ and the function $f' : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we can choose $r > 0$ such that $[x_0 - r, x_0 + r] \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [x_{0} - r, x_0 + r]$. Does the $f'(x) > 0$ part come from continuity? How does that follow?

Comment: @KevinCarlson yes it does claim that right after. how does that use continuity?

Comment: @stackofhay42: There is one $\delta_1$ such that $[x_0-\delta_1,x_0+\delta_1]\subseteq\mathcal O$ (because $\mathcal O$ is open), and one $\delta_2$ such that $f'(x) \in (0,2f'(x_0))$ for $x\in[x_0-\delta_2,x_0+\delta_2]$ (because $f'$ is continuous). If you let $r$ be the _smallest_ of these deltas, the interval $[x_0-r,x_0+r]$ will satisfy both conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x_0 \in \mathcal{O}$ where the latter is open, there exists an open interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0 + \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$. In particular,
$$
\left[x_0-\frac{\delta}{2},x_0+\frac{\delta}{2}\right] \subset (x_0-\delta,x_0 + \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{O}.
$$
You are also correct in saying that continuity is not required for this. Although as pointed out in the comments, the continuity of $f^\prime$ is used elsewhere in the proof you are referring to. Namely, we use the continuity of $f^\prime$ together with the fact that $f^\prime(x_0) > 0$ to ensure that $f^\prime > 0$ on $\left[x_0-\frac{\delta}{2},x_0+\frac{\delta}{2}\right]$.

To see why this is possible, it will be enough to establish the following result:

> **Lemma**. Let $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open set and $g :O \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function on $O$. Assume further that $x_0 \in O$ is such that $g(x_0) > 0$. Then, there exists a compact interval 
>   $$
> \left[x_0-{\delta},x_0+{\delta}\right] \subseteq {O}
> $$
>   on which $g$ is strictly positive.

To prove this, let $\epsilon := g(x_0)/2 > 0$. Using the continuity of $g$, we can find $\delta_1 > 0$ such that
$$
g(x_0) - g(x) \leq |g(x)-g(x_0)| < \epsilon = \frac{g(x_0)}{2}
$$
for all $x \in {O}$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta_1$. Hence, one has
$$
g(x) > \frac{g(x_0)}{2} > 0
$$
for all these $x$. On the other hand, because $O$ is open, we can find $\delta_2 > 0$ such that 
$$
\left[x_0-{\delta_2},x_0+{\delta_2}\right] \subseteq O.
$$
Taking $0 < \delta < \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then proves the lemma.

Comment: @TonyK Nowhere are we using the function $f^\prime$ in constructing this interval, only that $x_0 \in \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: How does continuity show $f' > 0$ on $[x_0 - r, x_0 + r]$?

Comment: @stackofhay42 Please see my edit.

Comment: thanks. i am new to this, and your edit made it really clear to me.